How to fix the issue: SolrCore can not parse a string
Please help me in this case about Solr service.
My server is running window server 2012 for Dspace opensource application. It usually have issue and stop Tomcat service. I checked in the Solr logging and saw an error in the image attached but I dont know what is it and how to fix it.
Error in SolrCore

Thank you,
I restarted Tomcat service and restarted server but can not fixed

Is your Dspace instance open to the public? If so, my guess is that somebody is submitting a bad query via the app (perhaps a bot) and that is why you are seeing such text on the message on the Solr logs.
